# Problem using conv2d - wrong tensor input shape

Tags: pytorch

I need to forward a tensor [1, 3, 128, 128] representing a 128x128 rgb image into a

```
nn.Conv2d(128,128,1)
```

but I get the error

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [128, 128, 1, 1], expected input[1, 3, 128, 128] to have 128 channels, but got 3 channels instead
```

PS: the image tensor is shaped as a 4d because the previous step is a nn.UpsamplingBilinear2d(size=None, scale_factor=2) which needs a 4d tensor as input

Comment: change it to nn.Conv2d(3,128,1) .  the 3 dictates the number of input channels (in your case, 3 input channels)

Comment: then out_channels must be 3 or is it correct to be set 128 if i need a 128x128 rgb image as output? @user2066337